# Link doctrine entities in API PLATFORM

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Hello everyone I want to link a **Category** entity with a **Product** one and I want to know if i should use a custom operation to do that or there is a better way to do that ?

```
          "LINK-CATEGORY-TO-PRODUCT"={
              "method"="PUT",
              "path"="/products/{id}/categories/{categoryId}",
              "controller"="App\Controller\LinkCategoryToProductController",
              "access_control"="is_granted('LINK', previous_object)",
              "openapi_context"= {
                  "summary"="Link and unlink a product to a category"
              }
          },
```

I really dont think that is the best way to do relations because if I have a big project with a lot of relationships I can't afford to do a custom operation per relationship.